# Error al capturar valor de un archivo de texto en java

Tags: java

Buenas tengo un error al momento de imprimir los resultados de un archivo de texto yo los separo con un `split` y creo un `String[] columns` y con un `String dato1 = String.valueOf(columns[0]);` le asigno el valor pero al imprimir este `String` no me trae como resultado todos los datos de ese archivo solo algunos les daré un ejemplo de como esta compuesto mi archivo de texto.

Figura 1:

```
fecha1   hora de e/s      13:36:57 13:43:22           6,24T  
fecha2   hora de e/s      13:43:40 13:53:22          10,77T  
fecha3   hora de e/s      13:53:47 14:03:56          11,56T  
fecha4   hora de e/s      14:04:40 14:13:47          11,13T  
fecha5   hora de e/s      14:14:16 14:22:36          12,33T
```

al momento de imprimir solo me imprime el valor de `10,77` hacia abajo el `6,24` no me lo toma pero si el archivo lo coloco de esta manera

Figura 2:

```
6,24T  
10,77T  
11,56T  
11,13T  
12,33T
```

si me los imprime bien pero el archivo de texto se genera automáticamente como se muestra en la `figura 1` este es el código utilizado.

```
  while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            columns = linea.split("  ");
            datos date = new datos();
            String dato1 = String.valueOf(columns[0]);
              System.out.println(dato1);
}
```

Comment: no termino de entender el problema. como separas por " " si no hay espacios? para que haces ese split?

Comment: es que hay otros datos aparte de ese solo quise hacer referencia a esa columna

Comment: Si colums es un array de String, hacer String.valueOf(columns[0]) no tiene sentido.

Comment: Tu problema es que split de " 6.24T" da dos elementos, uno con "" y otro con "6.24T"

Comment: bueno  amigo luego de eso yo paso esos datos a una lista y los muestro en una tabla

Comment: si amigo exactamente el problema esta en ese valor que en esa posición me lo toma en blanco

Comment: Ya te he puesto la solucion como respuesta ;)

Comment: Si el archivo tiene mas datos y no solo esos entonces no es reproducible el error, y la solucion que te dieron es valida pensando que los datos "vienen asi". Fijate que si no pones un ejemplo claro, se pierde tiempo tratando de llegar a la solucion.

Comment: buenas ya actualice la figura 1 es realmente como se trae el archivo de texto

Comment: Gracias. Fijate que esa linea es muy diferente a tu primer ejmplo. Ahora, estas tomando colummns[0] realmente? o eso es solo un ejemplo?

Comment: no tomo el indice [20] es la columna que le corresponde a esos datos yo ese lo tome como referencia.

Comment: todo esto que estas explicando ahora, hacen que la pregunta sea muy diferente, y la respuesta tambien.

Comment: bueno disculpen si no me supe explicar bien pero creo que ya esta bien formulada

Comment: el split lo haces por esos caracteres? todo el resto del codigo es correcto o es tambien un ejemplo?

Comment: estas en lo cierto el `split` lo hago con esos caracteres ya que los separo por espacios en blanco y el código es el que uso actualmente

Comment: que te impide hacer un split posicional en lugar de uno por espacios? porque por espacios no va a andar nunca porque los caracteres no estan todos separados por la misma cantidad de espacios.. es mas.. si te llega a venir 120T no se que vas a hacer

Comment: dime como seria la mejor manera de poder solucionar eso gracias por tormarte tu tiempo

Comment: Una pregunta inocente... lo que hay en medio de las columnas... ¿son espacios en blanco o tabulaciones?

Comment: solo hay espacios en blanco saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver esto tienes dos opciones:

Una es que cuando llegues a buscar el número, verifiques si realmente está en esa posición (es decir, que esa posición del vector no esté vacía).

Si no, yo recomendaría una lectura de la línea posicional, ya que todas las filas empiezan en el mismo lugar con un montón de espacios.

Entonces puedes hacer `linea.substring(0,7)` para obtener `fecha1`, y de ahí en más, hacer `linea.substring(8,15).trim()` para obtener `hora de e/s`, etcétera, entonces te evitas el problema si los espacios que vienen adelante son muchos o pocos.

Comment: gracias amigo justo lo que necesitaba así fue mas fácil que por el split desconocía que el substring podía hacer eso gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es convertir la línea que tiene 2 espacios o más en otra cosa(ej. -----) y luego hacer el split.

```
    while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
        //si hay 2 espacios o mas los convierte a -----
        String auxLinea = linea.replaceAll("(  +)","-----").trim();
        columns = auxLinea.split("-----");          
        String dato1 = String.valueOf(columns[3]);
          System.out.println(dato1);
    }
```

Otra opción sería usar una expresión regular y coger un numero separado por "," y que termine en "T".

```
String regex = "([0-9]+(\\,[0-9][0-9]?)?T)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(linea);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));         
}
```